# Find the nonzero vectors $u,v,w$ that are perpendicular to the vector $(1,1,1,1)$ and to each other

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the nonzero vectors $u,v,w$ that are perpendicular to the vector $(1,1,1,1)$ and to each other.

**Answer:**

If I follow algebra, then I get complicated results to solve it as follows:

Let $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4), \ v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4) , \ w=(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)$

Then, $u \cdot (1,1,1,1)=v \cdot (1,1,1,1)=w \cdot (1,1,1,1)=0$

Also $u \cdot v=w \cdot u=v \cdot w=0$.

These gives us

$u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4=0, \\ v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4=0 , \\ w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4=0, \\ u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3+u_4v_4=0, \\ u_1w_1+u_2w_2+u_3v_3+u_4v_4=0, \\ v_1w_1+v_2w_2+v_3w_3+v_4w_4=0. $

But how to solve for $u_i, v_i,w_i, \ i=1,2,3,4$ from here?

Does there exit any other easy method?

Help me out

Comment: Apply Gram-Schmidt to the basis $$((1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)),$$ or any other basis beginning with $(1, 1, 1, 1)$.

Comment: Is not in that case the solution will be particular , I mean there can other vectors also which can not be conclude using Gram-schmidt method.

Comment: Yes, it will be particular. If you range over all such bases, then you will obtain all orthonormal bases beginning with $\left(\frac12,\frac12,\frac12,\frac12\right)$, though not uniquely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as columns
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&-1&-1&-1 \\
1& 1&-1&-1 \\
1&0 &2&-1 \\
1&0&0&3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Pattern, done correctly,  works in any dimension

$$    
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  7  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  8  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  9   
\end{array}
  \right).
  $$

Comment: That's great! =)

Comment: Excellent method

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Hadamard matrix of which we know that the columns form an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The other columns would give you a solution.

Alternatively, use Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: But if we consider the Hadamard matrix , then the solution will be particular. There may be other vectors which are perpendicular to $(1,1,1,1)$ except the last 3 column vectors in the Hadamard vectors and its multiples .

Comment: So if we use Gram-Schmidt method then we need a basis

Comment: Theo has given you a basis right? Note that  answer is not unique. If you want to describe the set, you have already done so in your post.

Comment: There is a pattern that easily adapts to any dimension...